# How to add service provider into config/app providers array in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have installed these packages shown in the image:

[image]

and add these lines in providers array

[image]

but when I run this command got this error !!

[image]

Does there any changes happen in laravel 5.1 for adding packages service ??

I followed the instructions mentioned in the github repo. but got the same error.

Comment: did you use the command: `composer update` after adding the packages on your .json?

Comment: Yup i use dupautoload

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: yup.. in laravel 5.1 you can add service provider in two ways. one by using AppServiceProvider second directy by adding in providers array config/app.php. but difference is it is good to add ::class at the end.

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers

just go through this documentation.
Suppose:
I need to do this:-
Add the ServiceProvider of the package to the list of providers in the config/app.php file

'providers' => array(
    'Serverfireteam\Blog\BlogServiceProvider'
)

then, i would do this in

'providers' => [

```
    /*
    *Added by Amit for the blog
    */
    Serverfireteam\Blog\BlogServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documentation](https://github.com/wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf/tree/master#installation). It says that first of all you should add `wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf` to `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require": {            
    "wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf": "1.0.*"
  }
}
```

This can be done by running:

```
composer require wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf
```

Comment: My question is how add service provider and add aliases into config/app